# SENDING MAIL USING SSIS Send Mail Task

Tags: ssis

I want to send email with and attachment using SSIS, and the below error occurs.

> [Send Mail Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error
> message: "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client
> was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication
> Required. Learn more at".

Below is my SMTP connection Manager and Send Mail Task, and the above error occurs..

[image]

[image]

Any help..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide authentication, GMail doesn't work as an open relay.

Also, you can't connect to GMail with Windows authentication, so you'll have to use a script component and do this in .Net if that has to be your mail server for this.

Here's someone who found & solved this already, even including the GMail part: http://kalyan-coldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/send-email-with-ssisdatabase-from-gmail.html

Better luck with your Googling in future :)

Comment: But my question was how to use Send Mail Task ... The example is good but it's kind of trick ... What if i want to use Send Mail Task indeed??