# Pull a set of data through stored procedure and send an email

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I need to pull a set of data about users THROUGH a stored procedure and send an email to each of them on certain days. Using SSIS, what tasks I can use to do this? I CAN NOT USE Send Mail Task as I don't have access to a local SMTP server.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You can (*must*) set a connection to a specific SMTP server in the `Send Mail`'s connection property. There's no assumption that an SMTP server runs on the local machine. Just fill the connections with the address of the SMTP server you want to use

Comment: Hi Panagiotis,Thanks for replying. I know if i use Send mail task it will be really straight forward. But we use third party SMTP server we do not have our own. I have option of script task I assume, but do not know much about script task due to the complexity in the code :(

Comment: The Send Mail task in SSIS is asking for an SMTP Connection. I doubt whether it is possible with out an SMTP access?

Comment: Hi Jithin, I guess its mandatory field to put SMTP Connection details in send mail task, and will not allow you to progress further without SMTP details!!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. You can't send an email, from any program, if you don't know the address of the SMTP server. Are you saying you don't know the address of the external server, it requires credentials you don't have, it requires a non-standard port? Did you try to set the connection at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send Mail Task can talk to external/third-party mail servers. SMTP Connection Manager's SMTP server setting can be set to any valid Internet/intranet host name (external or internal). However, there's a catch: the SMTP Connection Manager's only authentication option is for Windows authentication. Most external SMTP servers require username/password authentication.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25654022/117424 talks about several ways to bypass this limitation.

Comment: Thanks Ben This will help . I might use Script Task in this case :)